# What the difference between anonymous classes based on interface and class

Tags: java

What the difference between anonymous classes based on interface and anonymous classes based on "normal" classes(non interfaces).

Comment: Why you asking (in the sense: I can't think of any special difference here)?

Comment: My friend is preparing for job interview and he got some questions(sample). And I wonder wheather there is some differences. Who knows that may be I will have same question one day=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interfaces, the anonymous class has to implement all methods. For classes, you don't have to, but you can override methods. If you're not overriding any methods you might as well just create a regular instance. It's exactly like implementing an interface in the first case and extend a class in the second.

Answer (score 1):

The exact same difference as a new class implementing an interface (`implements`) and subclassing a base class (`extends`).

The fact that the new class is anonymous makes no difference, it's just another class to the JVM.

The rest is compiler sugar.